# Run two scripts simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a web application in azure to host my application js node. (Azure web application)

In my project I have an api in express that is in the app.js, however in the same project I have another file which is a cronjob.

[image]

In my package.json I have the following configuration for script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
```

When deploying through github, the api that is in the app.js works perfectly.

My question: How do I run cronjob.js simultaneously with app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to running multiple scripts simultaneously is [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all).

Install with:

```
npm install --save npm-run-all
```

Then setup your "scripts" section in your package.json like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "app": "node app.js",
  "cronjob": "node cronjob.js",
  "start": "npm-run-all --parallel app cronjob"
}
```

And start with `npm start` as usual.

Answer (score 6):

You can start multiple application by using "pm2" node_module.

After installing pm2 module you can start your application by using the following command in terminal.

> pm2 start app.js && pm2 start cronjob.js

You may also use forever node module.

Comment: Using a process manager (like pm2) is a good idea even if you don't need to run multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

If the only requirement is that, I think there is no need to use another tool. Simply, you can achieve this with a single ampersand `&`.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js & node cronjob.js"
}
```